# How to return more than one array from a function in java

Tags: java, arrays, return

Is it possible in Java to return two or more arrays from a function

I tried to return two arrays  from a function normally but encountered an error

Comment: Are all of the arrays of the same data type? If so, you can return a `List` of arrays, for example: `List<int[]> myList = new ArrayList<int[]>();`

Comment: A method can return exactly one value.  That one value can be a reference to one array, or a reference to an object that contains references to other objects (such as arrays).  I suspect you might need to review the difference between objects and variables.

Comment: Show that code attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example for getting a `int[][]`:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static int[][] getArrays() {
        final int[] firstArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
        final int[] secondArray = new int[]{4, 5, 6};
        final int[][] result = new int[][]{firstArray, secondArray};
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      final int[][] arrays = MyClass.getArrays();
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < arrays[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arrays[i][j]);
          }
      }
    }
}
```

You can also do this with Lists, Sets, or Maps. For example:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static List<int[]> getArraysList() {
        final List list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        final int[] firstArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
        final int[] secondArray = new int[]{4, 5, 6};
        list.add(firstArray);
        list.add(secondArray);
        return list;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      final List<int[]> arraysList = MyClass.getArraysList();
      for (int[] intArray : arraysList) {
          for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
              System.out.println(intArray[i]);
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Or, more briefly:

```java
    public static List<int[]> getArraysList() {
        return 
            List.of(
                new int[]{1, 2, 3} , 
                new int[]{4, 5, 6}
            )  // Returns an unmodifiable list. 
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only return one value from a function in Java. If you want to return two arrays, you would need to create an array that holds those two arrays, also known as a 2D array, and return that. You create one in the same way as a single array, but you have two sets of brackets, i.e. `int[][] array_stuff = new int[2][7];` where there are 2 inner arrays that each contains 7 integers. You index these in the same way, `array_stuff[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0):

In java, a function can only return one return value, you can consider putting the array into a List or map and returning the value。

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it's not possible to directly return multiple arrays from a function, however, you can create a custom class which can hold numerous Arrays and by returning that class's object you can return numerous Arrays at once.

Example:

```
public class ArrayClass{
    private int[] array1;
    private string[] array2;

    public ArrayClass(int[] array1, String[] array2) {
        this.array1 = array1;
        this.array2 = array2;
    }
    
    public int[] getArray1() {
        return array1;
    }
    
    public String[] getArray2() {
        return array2;
    }
}
```

Now you can create an object of this class and return it.

```
public ArrayClass getArrays(int[] array1, string[] array2){
    return new ArrayClass(array1, array2);
}
```

This allows you to return both arrays as part of a single object.